# Initial Population of Genetic Algorithm

Tags: matlab, initialization, genetic-algorithm

How to generate the chromosome which is `x=[1 0;0 1;1 0;1 0] or [1 0;1 0;0 1;1 0]` like this.

I need to generate the chromosomes only with the help of "x=1 when ith machine is in cell l, otherwise 0 when i= no of machine and l= no of cell."

Matrix will be like this `[1 0;0 1;1 0;0 1] when i=4 & l=2.`

It means machine no 1&3 are in cell 1 and machine no 2&4 are in cell 2.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean. Can you help to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use an encoding `x[1,2,1,2]` instead of x`[1,0;0,1;1,0;0,1]`? And then use `randi([1,2],[4,1])` for initialization.
Your encoding is kind of redundant, or did I get the question wrong?

Alternatively you could do:

```
r = randi([1,2],[4,1]);

x = zeros(4,2);
for idx = 1:size(r,1);
    if r(idx) == 1
        x(idx,1) = 1;
    else
        x(idx,2) = 1;
    end
end
```